# Can someone help me figure out Oracle's (10g) AND/OR short circuitry?

Tags: oracle10g, short-circuiting

Consider the following query and notice the CALCULATE_INCENTIVE function:

```
SELECT EMP.* FROM EMPLOYEES EMPS
WHERE
    EMP.STATUS = 1 AND
    EMP.HIRE_DATE > TO_DATE('1/1/2010') AND
    EMP.FIRST_NAME = 'JOHN' AND
    CALCULATE_INCENTIVE(EMP.ID) > 1000
ORDER BY EMPS.ID DESC;
```

I was under the impression that Oracle uses the same (or similar) short-circuitry that .NET uses in its and/or logic.  For example, if EMP.STATUS = 2, it won't bother evaluating the rest of the expression since the entire expression would return false anyway.

In my case, the CALCULATE_INCENTIVE function is being called on every employee in the db rather than only on the 9 records that the first three WHERE expressions return.  I've even tried putting parenthesis around the specific expressions that I want to group together for short-circuit evaluation, but I can't figure it out.

Anyone have any ideas how to get the CALCULATE_INCENTIVE **not** to be evaluated if any of the previous expressions return false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to put the primary criteria into a subquery that Oracle can't optimize away, then put the secondary criteria into the outer query.  The easiest way to ensure that Oracle doesn't optimize out the subquery is to include rownum in the select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT EMP.*, ROWNUM 
   FROM EMPLOYEES EMPS
   WHERE
       EMP.STATUS = 1
       AND EMP.HIRE_DATE > TO_DATE('1/1/2010')
       AND EMP.FIRST_NAME = 'JOHN')
WHERE CALCULATE_INCENTIVE(ID) > 1000
ORDER BY EMPS.ID DESC;
```

Comment: Interesting that you propose this answer as this was the solution given to me in a question I asked just yesterday and is the ultimate route I have taken.  I know that Oracle supports short-circuit evaluation, though, and I am interested in figuring out how it make it work.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: Well that solution was fresh in my mind, since I had written it so recently.  Sorry, I didn't realize the OP was the same.  Still, this is the only (to my knowledge) way to force Oracle to short-circuit an evaluation in a specified manner.  As @Justin Cave points out, Oracle will short circuit conditions, but it does so based on the optimizer's path, not on the syntax of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports short-circuit evaluation in PL/SQL.  In SQL, however, the optimizer is free to evaluate the predicates in whatever order it desires, to push predicates into views and subqueries, and to otherwise transform the SQL statement as it sees fit.  This means that you should not rely on predicates being applied in a particular order and makes the order predicates appear in the WHERE clause essentially irrelevant.  The indexes that are available, the optimizer statistics that are present, the optimizer parameters, and system statistics are all vastly more important than the order of predicates in the WHERE clause.

In PL/SQL, for example, you can demonstrate this with a function that throws an error if it's actually called.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create function throw_error( p_parameter IN NUMBER )
  2    return number
  3  as
  4  begin
  5    raise_application_error( -20001, 'The function was called' );
  6    return 1;
  7* end;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    l_num NUMBER;
  3  begin
  4    l_num := 1;
  5    if( l_num = 2 and throw_error( l_num ) = 2 )
  6    then
  7      null;
  8    else
  9      dbms_output.put_line( 'Short-circuited the AND' );
 10    end if;
 11    if( l_num = 1 or throw_error( l_num ) = 2 )
 12    then
 13      dbms_output.put_line( 'Short-circuited the OR' );
 14    end if;
 15* end;
 16  /
Short-circuited the AND
Short-circuited the OR

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In SQL, on the other hand, the order of operations is determined by the optimizer, not by you, so the optimizer is free to short-circuit or not short-circuit however it wants.  Jonathan Gennick has a great article [Subquery Madness!](http://www.gennick.com/madness.html) that discusses this in some detail.  In your particular case, if you had a composite index on (FIRST_NAME, HIRE_DATE, STATUS) along with appropriate statistics, the optimizer would almost certainly use the index to evaluate the first three conditions and then only call the `CALCULATE_INCENTIVE` function for the ID's that met the other three criteria.  If you created a function-based index on `CALCULATE_INCENTIVE(id)`, the optimizer would likely use that rather than calling the function at all at runtime.  But the optimizer would be perfectly free to decide to call the function for every row in either case if it decided that it would be more efficient to do so.